# Static website at root domain hosted over a Blob Storage on Azure?

Tags: azure, dns, azure-blob-storage

I would like to host a static website [over the Blob Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website) of Microsoft Azure. Is it possible to have the website hosted at the root of the domain (aka `http://contoso.com` rather than `http://www.contoso.com`) while using the Blob Storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom domain mapping to an Azure Blob Storage static website works only for subdomains (for example: `www.contoso.com`).

If you want your web endpoint to be available on the root domain (for example: `contoso.com`), then you'll have to use Azure CDN [Map a custom domain with HTTPS enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-custom-domain-name?tabs=azure-portal#enable-https) or [Azure Static Web Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/custom-domain#configure-a-root-domain).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-custom-domain-name?tabs=azure-portal#map-a-custom-domain-with-https-enabled